# Sorting by taxonomy sub-term weight

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I've got troubles with a views sorting. I'm attempting to order the views output by a term's weight. The problem is that each taxonomy sub-term starts with weight 0, no matter what.
Is there a way to get around that, so that the sub-terms are displayed correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hook_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query)`
here you can pass extra sorting more sorting fields

http://www.chrisfree.me/2010/12/use-hookviewsqueryalter-handle-special-sort-cases
please check this link